# can't move content block to header Magento

Tags: magento

I am new magento. I try to play around structure block and content block. when I try to move "My Cart" block from right side to header section. It doesn't work. but once I move another block it works. ex:

```
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

this's work (it show on top page) but when I change reference to "head", this block just disappear. Please guild me.

here's the screenshot that I want.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0002ivnb10

Comment: You said head reference.. in terms of simple html if you put cart block  in your <head></head> html tag, then you will obvoiusly not see anything rendered in your browser. Hope you get the picture. The head reference is mainly to inject js and css files.

Answer (score 1):

You have to render the block manually by:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_actions'); ?>
```

in cart phtml template file

Header, head & cart blocks are not core/text_list blocks means they will not render their children automatically

Comment: Thanks !!! :) I can display now. but why some block is core/text_list but need to render manually such as <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>

Comment: Only core/text_list blocks render their children automatically, all other blocks needs to call getChildHtml method